# Java Firebase Admin SDK verify email error

Tags: java, firebase-authentication, firebase-admin

I am building a Rest API with Spring Boot and Firebase Auth using the Admin SDK.
I am creating the user in Firebase with this method:

```
@Override
public UserRecord createFirebaseUser(SignupRequest signupRequest) throws FirebaseAuthException {
    UserRecord user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().createUser(new UserRecord.CreateRequest()
            .setEmail(signupRequest.getEmail())
            .setDisplayName(signupRequest.getUsername())
            .setPassword(signupRequest.getPassword())
            .setEmailVerified(false)
            .setDisabled(false));
    generateVerificationLink(user.getUid());
    return user;
}



@Override
public String generateVerificationLink(String firebaseId) throws FirebaseAuthException {
    UserRecord firebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getUser(firebaseId);
    return FirebaseAuth.getInstance().generateEmailVerificationLink(firebaseUser.getEmail());
}
```

This method returns the following error response:

```
com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuthException: Unexpected HTTP response with status: 400
{
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "TOO_MANY_ATTEMPTS_TRY_LATER",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "TOO_MANY_ATTEMPTS_TRY_LATER",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "invalid"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

This doesn't make a lot of sense to me as I am only sending the request once per user, and I always get this error. Does anybody know what I have to fix?